# Apache Spark Outer Join Taking long time

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new in Spark. I have Two Spark SQl Dataframes. The code goes something like this

```
val df1 = sparksql.read.format(com.databricks.avro).loadfiles(filespath)

val df2 = sparksql.sql(select * from hivedb)

val df3 = df1.join(df2,df1.srcid <=> df2.srcid and df1.srccode <=> df2.srccode, left_outer)

sqlcontext.cacheastable(""table)

val insertid = sparkcontext.sql("select * from table where cid is null")

val updateid = sparkcontext.sql("select * from table where cid is not null")
```

then we save these two df to database.

Both data frames contain around 10 fields like `srcid`, `stccode`, and customer details like first name, last name etc. They are small strings which were originally varchar in oracle table.

Both dataframes have around 3 million records.

When we run the job we see a lot of slowness as Executioner takes around 2 hours to complete its computation. We tried many settings like left broadcast join and setting number of partitions but to no avail.

When data is small (50K files) the job is completed in 6 mins. I saw Spark UI and only spark execution computation is taking place.

We have even set Memory per executioner 12 G and Given it 24 Executioners with NUM cores as 20.

We are using Spark 1.5.0 which comes bundled with Cloudera 5.X cluster and running with Yarn.

Can you please let me know where can I debug the slowness aside from spark context?

Comment: I have added the code example here . Hope that help. We need to run this join in spark and save data back to Oracle DB

Answer (score 0):

One way i would suggest is, checking the physical plan of your df3 and ensure you do not have cross product at the end. Another one is, check your `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` and increase it, if it is lower. Use some where around 200.

Optimizing joins in very important task and it needs analyzing lot of things. Also, make sure you turned on tungsten. set `spark.sql.tungsten.enabled` to true.

Check it after these and let me know. 1.5.0 will be bit slower for joins, as i do not think it had full list of optimizations added. Nevertheless, check these and let me know.

Comment: Hi Srini.. We do have Tugsten enabled and number of partions are 200 as well . I checked that out in the Spark UI.. I see the physical plan and do see a exchange. Is that same as cross product. If yes  then how to remove it...I will provide the physical plan in next comment

Comment: What about partitions.?

Comment: I can not copy paste the physical plan as it is long here.. I have written below the syntax of the physical plan

Comment: Plan goes something like this  Attributes .....BroadcastNestedLoopJoin BuildLeft, LeftOuter, Some ,some attributes ........Exchange hashpartitioning(Srccode#2,SRCid#1)
    Aggregate true.... SOme Attributes .......Project  Some Attributes ....Scan AvroRelation[hdfs://xxxxxA/xxx/xx/xxx/xxxx/xxx/xxxxx] and same attributes

Comment: Can i split the input the input df into smaller DF or there is better way of doing the join...How can i solve this... One way i was think was to split the input df into into 5 ,6 smaller DF and do the join... But that wontt solve this issue in long term... If you can let me know of a way of doing join that will be much appriciated

Comment: Can you add persists(cache if the data is lesser) on df1 and df2 and check.

Comment: Hi Srini.. THis looks like dataframe issue. When i am doing join using Key Value, the join is done in 2 minutes.  It does not work in dataframe after 2 hours as well after doing cache table also

Comment: This issue wa fixd. The issue was that if you have null's in input keys , spark creates a cartsian join. We have fixed this by removing the nulls from keys

Answer (score 0):

This issue wa fixd. The issue was that if you have null's in input keys , spark creates a cartsian join. We have fixed this by removing the nulls from keys